# Demo a Proprietary Signal Processing Algorithm Without Cheating

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

I have a proprietary signal processing algorithm, $F(s)$, which I would like to demo to my customers. The demo starts with the customer uploading a binary signal $S_0$ to my website. I then generate a response signal $R = F(S_0)$ and return it to the customer. The customer then adds some amount of noise to the response $R^{'} = \Psi(R)$, and uploads the noisy signal $R^{'}$. Finally I generate a close approximation of the original signal $S_1 = F^{-1}(R^{'})$ and return it to the customer for comparison to the original $S_0$.

How can I do this so there is no doubt that I am being honest and using only $R^{'}$ as the input to $F^{-1}$ to generate $S_1$?

Comment: What about making a demo where $F$ (or $F^{-1}$, whichever requires the less computing power or is less confidential) sits inside a Smart Card usable only once, or a limited number of times, that you hand to the customer? Some now have 1MByte of Flash, 50kB of RAM, a 50 MHz 32-bit CPU, for few $

Comment: @fgrieu Nice idea. Do you have a link to such a Smart Card?

Comment: In alphabetical order of what I have in mind, [SLC37](https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/security-smart-card-solutions/security-controllers/slc37/), [ST33J](https://www.st.com/en/secure-mcus/st33j2m0.html). These are not easy to procure, though, and the "few $" is excluding NRE. If that's only for a few, your best bet might be some of [these](https://www.smartcardfocus.com/shop/ilp/se~71/so~5/sr~/ps~2/p/index.shtml), but expect a hit on performance and memory size.

Comment: I feel like there's some sort of zero-knowledge proof system that might be able to do this, but I'm not particularly familiar with that field (and it's a very active area of research, so probably not anything production ready).